# VBA - force excel to save in custom format

Tags: vba, excel

For a project at work i would like to allow the user to create an export of data to be saved for a single project, since it will not be possible to save my main workbook for each project.

I have created a function that exports the data to another workbook, but now i want to make sure that the user won't change the exported data directly (By setting another file format, i think the users would think more about opening the workbook, and therefore not do it by "accident")

So my question is:
Can i force the user to save the file as a .clg file?

**Edit:**

I solved the problem by saving the file with `.SaveAs` and specifying the format as "51" (The same as .xlsx"). I used `GetSaveAsFilename` to allow the user to decide the location (i.e. the project folder), and only browse for .clg files.

```
Dim sFullName As String
sFullName = exportFile.Application.GetSaveAsFilename(thisFile.Sheets("Project information").Cells(1, 2).Value, "Export files (*.clg),*.clg", , "Choose export location", "Export")
If Not Len(sFullName) = 0 Or sFullName = "False" Then

    exportFile.SaveAs Filename:=sFullName, FileFormat:=51

End If

exportFile.Close
```

If someone wants to use Mr. Monshaw's approach, one way to go is to create a class module, which has a variable withevents - which means that any event that fires in the variable, fires in your module.

```
Public WithEvents wbk As Workbook
```

Just remember to keep the instance of the class in memory, for example by adding it to a collection.

Another way to use the `BeforeSave` is to dynamically write the code, see http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=163903

Comment: Why not just protect the exported worksheet(s)?

Comment: People don't like it if you tell them that the file is there, but they can't open/edit them. Better to "hide" them - i.e. making it harder to open them

Comment: Do you read the file in another program?

Comment: No, only in the same Excel workbook when the user want to do an import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 'clg' a format you use? or just a random not xls/x extension?

If the file does need to be viewed and viewed in excel (guessing your not exporting windows catalogue files?) then changing the extension might not be the best move.

If you create your export using VBA, then you can automate some things to make it more apparent to the users that they should not be editing the data.

The `Workbook.SaveAs` method has the option for "ReadOnlyRecommended" which will inform the user that the workbook should be opened read-only when opening it. (its optional though, so they could ignore it)

Assuming the data is always read-only you could also lock the workbook so that no changes can be made.

*Update*

If you want to save an Excel Workbook with a custom extension (and not as a custom format) then using the `Workbook.SaveAs` method will work. ex: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Report.clg"`

You'll either need to have your export code do this for you, or if its a more manual process you can just create a macro with a button to invoke the save-as for you instead of using the standard save-as dialogue.

If you want to save as a custom format, and it is not one of the ones supported by `Workbook.SaveAs` ([supported formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)) you will have to do as @Mr.Monshaw suggested and watch for the onbeforesave and generate the file manually. (unlikely someone has done an excel to windows catalogue converter)

Comment: 'clg' is the format that i semi-randomly choosed, so that double clicking the file won't open Excel.

The user is not supposed to open the file, other than through an import function in the same workbook as the export is happening from.

The data should not be read-only, since i might have to change it (using vba) later.

Comment: Using `Workbook.SaveAs` should do it then.

Comment: How can `Workbook.SaveAs` do the trick? I'm not sure i follow you here?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the constant for clg would be but the fileformat property of SaveAs in vba would allow you to decide what format to save in

i saw a clever solution to something similar to this if you can find the fileformat, just add a macro to your book with a workbook event like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Call SaveAsCLG(SaveAsUI)          'set save type
    Cancel = True                                 'cancel user save

End Sub
```

that will override a user save-as request

Comment: You see, the thing is that since the exported document is just a new document, and then copy/paste data in there, i can't write VBA in the new document

Comment: im afraid i dont understand

Comment: I have a document, where users can enter information and get some documents generated based on a lot of templates and calculations. But since the document has so much code, i don't want it copied to every project that it is used for. Therefore i have created a export function, but i don't want to save the exported document as an excel document.

Comment: I just fund a way to intercept with the `BeforeSave` event, from my other document, so maybe your suggestion will work anyway - but can you please ellaborate?

Comment: what you would do is take their saveAs request and turn it into your own file type instead of whatever they wanted then cancel their original save request

Comment: Now i have tried to implement a test function on `BeforeSave`, but it seems to fire the event, before the user actually saves the document?

Comment: No, it is in a seperate class module

Comment: to my understanding it needs to be in the thisworkbook module to fire correctly...you could dynamically write it into the copies of the book you make though

Comment: I found another solution, with a `msoFileDialog` and `SaveAs`, and edited origial post. I also left a clue on how i tried to implement your solution.